# Connection to Database and Create a database in Node

Tags: mysql, node.js

[I've tried to implement this code and terminal throws error something like this stucked in it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TxtnE.png) As I've applied this code but it throws the error
"Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'mydb'"

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "myusername",
  password: "mypassword"
});

con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Connected!");
  /*Create a database named "mydb":*/
  con.query("CREATE DATABASE mydb", function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Database created");
  });
});
```

Comment: see if you can access `mysql` from terminal

Comment: as I have got the Connected message on console but can't able to create database from that code

Comment: could you try only `.connect` without the `con.query`?

Comment: Yess, it's working without con.query

Comment: well there you go, you could move your `con.query()` outside

Comment: outside con.connect? It's not working still..

Comment: test from console if you can create database, looks like mysql permission issue

Comment: issue solved as I have set the username to 'root' btw thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> create a config folder and create a file databaseConfig.js

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

config = {
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'root',
  password: '',
  database: '<DB name>'
}
var connection =mysql.createConnection(config); //added the line
connection.connect(function(err){
if (err){
   console.log('error connecting:' + err.stack);
}
   console.log('connected successfully to DB.');
});

module.exports ={
   connection : mysql.createConnection(config) 
}
```

> create a app.js file

```
var express = require('express');
var cors = require('cors');
app = express(),
app.use(cors()),
port = process.env.PORT || 3001;
bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
var routes = require('./api/routes/routes'); //importing route
routes(app);
console.log('todo list RESTful API server started on: ' + port);
app.listen(port);
```

> create a controller.js file

```
var config = require('../../databaseConfig.js');
var connection= config.connection
connection.query ('CREATE DATABASE mydb', function(error, results){
  if (results){
     console.log(results);
  }  
  else{
     console.log(error);
  }
});
```

Comment: This answer has nothing to do with `access denied`